# How to connect router to ISP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I'm in Sydney, Australia, with TPG.

```
Configuration Option    PPPoE ADSL2+ Static IP
TPG services:
dns: 203.12.160.35 and 203.12.160.36
smtp: mail.tpg.com.au
pop3: mail.tpg.com.au
news: news.tpg.com.au
ntp: ntp1.tpg.com.au and ntp2.tpg.com.au
```

My router is a TP-LINK TD-W8968.

I've done the "quick setup" on the router, and correctly input my PPPoE username and password. But there's still no connection to the internet. I've paid for a static IP (which is also listed on the TPG customer interface but i haven't included in this post for privacy reasons) so I entered the "advanced config" menu on the router and configured the WAN settings to a static IP address, however even after saving settings and rebooting the router, the statistics page reports a WAN IP address of 0.0.0.0 and no connection to the internet.

I've also checked all cables. I am able to make calls on the landline.

What might I be missing?

EDIT:

I am able to connect to the internet successfully with a different router provided by the ISP (a belkin54g). So it's not a problem on their end. I'm just not sure how to replicate the relevant configuration settings from the belkin router to the TP-LINK one (I'm not sure exactly what the relevant settings even are; i would have thought just the PPPoE username and password, and the static IP should do it)

Comment: Call your ISP for support.

Comment: @DavidPostill see edit

Comment: Since it's ADSL, did you configure the correct PVC (virtual circuit)? Not all ISPs use the same value.